# Run existing Ubuntu 16.04 as headless

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have been trying to look up for this,but didn't find anything that could help. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04, and its running alright. But, most of my work is on MAC except when I have to run some GPU-related tasks, which I run on Ubuntu. So, I am thinking if its possible that I 'ssh' into Ubuntu from MAC, and use it just like a server - in headless, static IP, not-asking-password at restart mode?

For now, I can ssh and work, but I cannot restart and provide password without having to plug-in monitor.

I have tried to setup Static IP by modifying interfaces file, but when I restart network-service, I lose internet connection. Wifi sign turns into up-down arrow and thats that.

**EDIT**: Interfaces file

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)                                       
auto lo                                                                                  
iface lo inet loopback                                                                   

#auto wlx60e3270fae59                                                                    
#iface wlx60e3270fae59 inet static                                                       
#address 192.168.100.2                                                                   
#gateway 192.168.100.1                                                                   
#netmask 255.255.255.0                                                                   
#dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.100.1
```

**Edit**
**Interface details:**

```
wlx60e3270fae59 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:e3:27:0f:ae:59  
          inet addr:192.168.100.2  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b02d:a1db:4f5f:7d19/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1549693 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:924620 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2048591560 (2.0 GB)  TX bytes:269411566 (269.4 MB)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: SSH does not depend upon the desktop. You don't need to be logged into the desktop for SSH to work just fine. Does your GPU-related task require a desktop interface?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But, in case, on restart, IP of the machine changes, or it requires password on login, I won't be able to do ssh unless I go check the IP using some other method or plugging in monitor and checking manually. In my case, GPU-related tasks don't require desktop interaction.

I need it to be exactly like a server, but can't reinstall as a server. I have spent few days setting it up, so would be quite a time wastage.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `interfaces` file. We suspect it is faulty.

Comment: Does the router in charge of this network belong to you? Or somebody else? Are you able to log into it's admin interface?

Comment: Is it possible that 192.168.100.2 is within the DHCP pool in the router? Have you verified that the interface is actually wlx60e3270fae59 ; no typos? If you uncomment all the entries and simply reboot, do you get the requested IP address?

Comment: Yes, I can login to the router.
no, when I reboot by uncommenting, it doesn't work. I have edited the post with interface details.

Also, I'll check the DHCP pool in the router and will get back.

Comment: So, I have checked in the router, and I see the IP for this and other devices in 'DHCP information'. Does it mean, I'll have to remove it from there after making modifications in interfaces file?

Comment: you have a few options in order to provide a static ip (to keep it between restarts) for the headless machine, either configure it on the machine (`/etc/network/interfaces`) or reserve an ip on the router and relate it to the `Mac Address`  (`60:e3:27:0f:ae:59`).

Comment: Most routers have a pool for DHCP addresses, like this: http://www.abyssunderground.co.uk/images/router/dhcp.gif In this example, the DHCP is using x.100 to x.149. You must assign any static IP address *OUTSIDE* the DHCP range. I suggest that you check the router and adjust your interfaces file.

Comment: x.100 to x.149 or x.110 to x.159? I will try a static IP outside this range.